# Quickbase - Setting initial default values but allow them to be changed

Tags: quickbase

Old dog learning new tricks here.  Long time .NET guy transitioning to QB...

I have a form that needs to have (on edit and add):

1. An initial selection in the first field (dropdown).
2. Several fields auto-populate based on the first field (also dropdowns).
3. A subset of the auto-populated fields from #2 need to be editable.  This needs to happen when the initial selection field is changed.

Example scenario:

I have used lookup fields and form values to attempt to accomplish this.  I can accomplish #1 and #2, but #3 does not work.  Either the auto-populated values change with the selection of the initial value but cannot be updated (they revert to the original value), or the form rules allow for auto-populating the values and editing, but this can only happen once.  If the  user changes the initial value for a second time, the first selection auto-populated values remain.

I know there are probably ways to do this by bouncing between several pages, but we are re-working an existing app and the desired approach is to keep it as much of a "one-pager" as possible.

Also, this functionality should happen without having to save the record.

I have added an attachment that maybe makes the above clearer???

Thanks in advance for any advice y'all can provide.

[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2LVt.png)